# List in nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

What I want is this:

```
Dic = {'name':{'id':[1,2,3]}}
```

I have seen answers of how to do this but the ones I saw required the list to be known when they are inserting. the problem I have is I don't know when I'll have to insert in `Dic['name']['id']`.

Is there a way to make something like this `Dic['name']['id'].append(0)`?

What I did before was this

```
Dic={}
Dic['name']=[] 
Dic['name'].append('id')
```

but now I have to store some values of ID too and those are *list* of values.

Comment: Why not just start with `{"name": {"id": []}}`?

Comment: I can't start it like this. 
the thing is I have to really do this. Dic['name']={} then Dic['name']['id']=[] but that didnt work

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"really do this"*, but if you start with an empty list you can certainly `.append` to it. Maybe some more context would be helpful?

Comment: [Edit] the question to give a [mre]. What's the *problem* with that?

Comment: What I Did before was this 
Dic={}
Dic['name']=[]
Dic['name].append('id')

but now I have to store some values of ID too and those are LIST of Values

Comment: Given the structure you say you want, it's unclear why you thought that `{"name": ["id"]}` made sense as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` to get what you want, for example:

```py
from collections import defaultdict


d = {'name': defaultdict(list)}
d['name']['id'].append(0)
d['name']['id'].append(1)
d['name']['id'].append(2)

print(d)
>>> {'name': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'id': [0, 1, 2]})}
```

Comment: It would probably need to be deeper if that's really what the OP is after: `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`

Comment: This worked tho Thanks a lot but is why is this not working Dic={} -> Dic['name']={} -> Dic['name']['id']=[] -> Dic['name']['id'].append(0).

Comment: @Osfort it should work, that's another way of doing it.

Comment: @Osfort what do you mean not working? That *will* work, resulting in `{"name": {"id": [0]}}`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The solution provided by "Marcos" works but the method I am trying to do( which I have mentioned in the prev. comment) does not work.

Comment: @Osfort you're wrong, it **does** work. It gives `Dic` the value in my previous comment.

Comment: @jonrsharpe IT WORKS!!!! I don't know how but now it works. so I asked the question and I had the solution too. Thanks Marcos and John.

Comment: @Osfort that's why making a [mre] is important - sometimes you solve the problem yourself in the process. Don't make assumptions, only post what you can prove with an example.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the next time @jonrsharpe. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dic = {}
Dic['name'] = {}
Dic['name']['id'] = []
Dic['name']['id'].append(0)
print(Dic)
```

This code segment gives the following output

```
{'name': {'id': [0]}}
```

I think this is the output you need

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question.

Comment: What if the "Dic" is empty and we want to make something like this, then what's the method?